# Add data attributes to Cartthrob form tags

Tags: cartthrob

Is it possible - without an extension or hack - to add `data-` attributes to CartThrob's form tags?

```
{exp:cartthrob:save_customer_info_form data-foo="bar"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code, I'd say not. In the form builder CartThrob uses, these are the only permitted form attributes:

```
protected $attributes = array('id', 'class', 'name', 'onsubmit', 'enctype');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this same situation, instead of hacking cartthrob to accomplish, just modify the element after the form is created with some javascript to add the data-* attribute:

```
<script>
    var checkout_form=document.getElementById('checkout');
    checkout_form.setAttribute("data-somekey", "someval");
</script>
```

Not beautiful but simple and it works!